# Adding manual colour palette to pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having some troubles with adding manually created color palette to pie chart.

Let's consider my pie chart function - it has the feature following : if value in % is less or equal 4% then this value will be beside pie chart with arrow followed.

```
pie_chart <- function(vec,col){
  df <- as.data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1] <- 'group'
  df$label <- paste0(df$Freq,' (', percent(df$Freq / sum(df$Freq)),')')
  df$angle <- ((cumsum(df$Freq) - 0.5 * df$Freq) / sum(df$Freq) * 360) %% 180 - 90
   ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = group)) +
    geom_col(width = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +scale_fill_brewer(palette=col)+
    geom_text(
      aes(x = ifelse(Freq/sum(Freq) < 0.04, 1.8, 1),
          y = sum(Freq) - (cumsum(c(0, Freq[-length(Freq)])) + 0.5 * Freq),
          label = label, angle = angle),
      position = position_identity(), vjust = 0.25,
      size = 4
    ) +  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.6, xend = 1.5,
                          y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                          yend = after_stat(y),
                          colour = I(ifelse(rev(Freq) / sum(Freq) < 0.04, "black",
                                            "transparent"))),
                      arrow = arrow(length = unit(1, "mm"))) +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    theme_void()
}
pie_chart(vec=c(rep(1,30),rep(2,40),rep(3,2)),col="Greens",save=0)
```

[image]

Problem I'm facing occurs when trying to change color palette to manually created.

```
pie_chart <- function(vec){

load(paste0(getwd(),'/my_palette'))
  df <- as.data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1] <- 'group'
  df$label <- paste0(df$Freq,' (', percent(df$Freq / sum(df$Freq)),')')
  df$angle <- ((cumsum(df$Freq) - 0.5 * df$Freq) / sum(df$Freq) * 360) %% 180 - 90
   ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = group)) +
    geom_col(width = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +scale_color_manual(values = my_palette)+
    geom_text(
      aes(x = ifelse(Freq/sum(Freq) < 0.04, 1.8, 1),
          y = sum(Freq) - (cumsum(c(0, Freq[-length(Freq)])) + 0.5 * Freq),
          label = label, angle = angle),
      position = position_identity(), vjust = 0.25,
      size = 4
    ) +  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.6, xend = 1.5,
                          y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                          yend = after_stat(y),
                          colour = I(ifelse(rev(Freq) / sum(Freq) < 0.04, "black",
                                            "transparent"))),
                      arrow = arrow(length = unit(1, "mm"))) +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
    theme_void()
}
pie_chart(vec=c(rep(1,30),rep(2,40),rep(3,2)))
```

[image]

And as you can see I got something very strange in output and I'm thinking why.
The thing which is very important to notice is that problem do not occurs without arrows. I think the problem might be there but I'm not so sure about it.Is this a problem connected with my manually created color palette that it's not capable to include arrows ? Or I wrote the code incorrectly ?

Comment: The issue is that you use `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: You are welcome. Always glad to help. However, I would say that your issue is more like a "typo". That's why I did not post it as an answer.